# Optional parameters to a FactoryGirl factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

So I have two models. A boat `has_many` users, and a dock `belongs_to` a user. Additionally, a `dock` has a `boat`. In the dock factory, I'm trying to create a user for that dock, and pass it to boat to create its array of users. As an additional requirement, I need the factory for boat to take temp_user as an **optional parameter.** Here's my attempt below.

```
  factory :dock do
    temp = user
    boat temp
  end 

  factory :boat do | temp_user |
    users { [ temp_user || FactoryGirlDefaultMethods.default_user ] }
    ....
  end
```

This seems to result in `NoMethodError: undefined method 'read_uploader' for nil:NilClass`. I'm not sure how to debug this, or how to correct it. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
The error is coming from an unrelated problem, but a `boat` is not being created for the `dock`, let alone with the correct user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by doing

```
  factory :dock do
    user
    boat { build :boat, users: [user] }
  end 

  factory :boat do 
    ....
  end
```